# KML to Dat Converter?

Tags: kml, file-formats, kmz

Are there any free KML to DAT(destinator compatible) converter available ? I tried to use global mapper but was in vain. Also used ITN converter but the line was converted to points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check out the website from Zonums Software tools online ? I am not sure if they have one for DAT converter. Maybe contact them about that.

Comment: I used ITNConverter but I get points for line I have drawn